# Ways to improve this SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance, sql-limit

I have this query

```
SELECT "items".*
FROM
    "items"
    INNER JOIN
    item_mods ON item_mods.item_id = items.id AND item_mods.mod_id = 15
WHERE (items.league_id = 1) AND (items.item_type_id = 11) AND (num_sockets >= 2)
ORDER BY item_mods.total_value DESC
LIMIT 25
```

This is the explain http://explain.depesz.com/s/dbf

```
"Limit  (cost=55739.84..55739.90 rows=25 width=554) (actual time=18065.470..18065.478 rows=25 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=55739.84..55741.90 rows=824 width=554) (actual time=18065.468..18065.471 rows=25 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: item_mods.total_value"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5871.95..55716.59 rows=824 width=554) (actual time=285.806..18055.589 rows=610 loops=1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on items  (cost=5871.52..20356.70 rows=4339 width=550) (actual time=201.543..10028.684 rows=9945 loops=1)"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((item_type_id = 11) AND (num_sockets >= 2))"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4120"
"                    Filter: (league_id = 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1125"
"                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=5871.52..5871.52 rows=4808 width=0) (actual time=199.322..199.322 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_items_on_item_type_id  (cost=0.00..289.61 rows=15625 width=0) (actual time=38.699..38.699 rows=16018 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (item_type_id = 11)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_items_on_num_sockets  (cost=0.00..5579.49 rows=301742 width=0) (actual time=158.441..158.441 rows=301342 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (num_sockets >= 2)"
"              ->  Index Scan using index_item_mods_on_item_id on item_mods  (cost=0.43..8.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.803..0.803 rows=0 loops=9945)"
"                    Index Cond: (item_id = items.id)"
"                    Filter: (mod_id = 15)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 9"
"Total runtime: 18065.773 ms"
```

How can I improve the speed of this query? I note there is a loop > 9000 times on the index scan

Comment: which table does `num_sockets` column belong to?

Comment: Can you show the DDL of both tables, including any indexes? Next, do you really need *all* the fields from [items]?

Comment: Which of your WHERE conditions are stable? What is the range of values a possible partial index would have to cover? How are the tables related? 1:n, n:m, n:1, ...? Does every item have item_mod(s)?

Comment: @DipenduPaul: Deducing form the explain output (`index_items_on_num_sockets)`, it should be `index.num_sockets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your query is slow is because there are no indexes for the way you want to return the data.

Notice the "Bitmap Index Scan" where it is saying, I know you have an index but I have to look at the whole table to find the row I need (hence total row scan of up to 301742!). This is probably because of the combination of other columns you have asked for and the constraints you are applying i.e. item_mods.mod_id = 15

Try:

1. "items".* - Only select out the columns you need rather than everything.
2. Create an index on: item_mods.item_id AND item_mods.mod_id
3. Create an index on: items.league_id AND items.item_type_id AND num_sockets (assuming num_sockets is on the same table)

Any performance difference?

Comment: In this case creating the 2 indexes has helped substantially

Answer (score 1):

This only shortens and cleans the syntax, but doesn't change anything substantially:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   items     i
JOIN   item_mods m ON m.item_id = i.id
WHERE  i.league_id = 1
AND    i.item_type_id = 11
AND    i.num_sockets >= 2
AND    m.mod_id = 15
ORDER  BY m.total_value DESC
LIMIT  25;
```

A query like this is **very hard** to optimize. Postgres cannot just read from the top of the index. since you are sorting by a column in `item_mods`, but the most selective conditions are on `items`, it is also hard to tailor an index that would help some more.

Of course you can optimize indexes on either table. But without additional information to feed to the query, it won't get cheap. *All* qualifying rows have to be read before Postgres knows the winners.

We have developed solutions under this related question on dba.SE. Sophisticated stuff:
[Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500)

Comment: Yeah, I've found the only way is to add very specific indexes. In my case the read speed is far more important than the insert speed. So I plan on adding in a lot more indexes. For example league_id will appear in almost every query so I was planning on adding indexes for [league_id,item_type_id] and [league_id, num_sockets]

Comment: @NickBarrett: Be sure you only keep those indices that are actually used. One multi-column index for each table should be all you need for this query - unless you operate with partial indexes.

Comment: Erwin, my knowledge of indexes is limited. If I create an index for [league_id, item_type_id, num_sockets] is that better than 2 indexes [league_id,item_type_id] and [league_id, num_sockets] . Thanks

Comment: @NickBarrett: Well, yes. But "better" is defined by the sum of all requirements and conditions. Partial indexes might be even faster - but only work for a narrowly defined set of queries. Showing 1 query doesn't give the full picture. I don't know the range of possible queries to cover, the table definition, cardinalities, data distribution. There is much finesse in indexing ...

Answer (score 0):

Below query should give a better performance as filtration is done before joining.

```
   SELECT t.* 
   FROM
   (
     SELECT items.* FROM items
     WHERE  (items.league_id = 1) AND (items.item_type_id = 11) 
   ) t 
   INNER JOIN 
   (
      SELECT item_mods.*
      FROM item_mods
      WHERE item_mods.mod_id = 15 
   ) s
   ON s.item_id = t.id 
   WHERE (num_sockets >= 2)
   ORDER BY item_mods.total_value DESC
   LIMIT 25
```

`num_sockets>=2` can also be included in some inner query if it is known which table it belongs to.

Please let me know if it performed better or not.

Comment: Most probably this is not going to help. Postgres would be smart enough to apply the conditions in an optimized sequence either way. The problem with this query is of principal nature.

Comment: Erwin is right, this query was interpreted exactly the same by the optimizer